# Add input fields based on number selection from drop-down in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Per my previous question, I have toggled the radio buttons correctly and everything works perfectly. Please run the snippet to test.

Now, where my drop-down field under Team -> Live Session used to add new inputs, now it doesn't work any more.

My 'Number of Attendees:" used to work perfectly when clicking on "6" it would add an extra input box and delete when clicking "5" again.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Picture for reference:

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('input[name=requestType]').click(function() {
  if(this.value == 'Team')
  {
   $(".total").show();
   $(".teamname").show();
   $(".one").show();
   $(".two").show();
   $(".three").show();
   $(".four").show();
   $(".five").show();
  }
  else
  {
   $(".teams").hide();
  }
 });
   $('#remoteSession').click(function() {
    if($('input[name=requestType]:checked').val() == 'Team')
    {
     $(".teams").hide();
      $(".teamname").show();
      $(".userCount").show();
    }
    else
    {
     $(".userCount").hide();
    }
   });
    $('#singleUser').click(function() {
    if($('input[name=sessionType]:checked').val() == 'Remote Session')
    {
     $(".userCount").hide();   
     }
   });
   $('#liveSession').click(function() {
    if($('input[name=requestType]:checked').val() == 'Team')
    {
     $(".one").show();
     $(".two").show();
     $(".three").show();
     $(".four").show();
     $(".five").show();
   $(".five").show();
   $(".total").show();
   $(".userCount").hide();
   $("#totalUsers").show();
    }
 });
 
 $("#totalUsers").change(function() {
  $('.six').hide();
  $('.seven').hide();
  $('.eight').hide();
  $('.nine').hide();
  $('.ten').hide();
  
  var selectValue = $(this).val();
  
  switch (selectValue) {
    case "six":
      $('.five').show();
      $('.six').show();
      break;
    case "seven":
      $('.five').show();
      $('.six').show();
      $('.seven').show();
      break;
    case "eight":
      $('.five').show();
      $('.six').show();
      $('.seven').show();
      $('.eight').show();
      break;
    case "nine":
      $('.five').show();
      $('.six').show();
      $('.seven').show();
      $('.eight').show();
      $('.nine').show();
      break;
    case "ten":
      $('.five').show();
      $('.six').show();
      $('.seven').show();
      $('.eight').show();
      $('.nine').show();
      $('.ten').show();
      break;
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.teams, .userCount
{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
 <div class="container form">
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="requestType" class="col-form-label">Request Type:</label>
    <label for="singleUser" class="radio-inline"><input id="singleUser" type="radio" name="requestType" value="Single User" checked>Single User</label>
  <label for="teamSelection" class="radio-inline"><input id="teamSelection" type="radio" name="requestType" value="Team">Team</label>
  
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="sessionType" class="col-form-label">Session Type:</label>
    <label for="liveSession" class="radio-inline"><input id="liveSession" type="radio" name="sessionType" value="Live Session" checked>Live Session</label>
  <label for="remoteSession" class="radio-inline"><input id="remoteSession" type="radio" name="sessionType" value="Remote Session">Remote Session</label>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row requester req">
   <label for="requesterName" class="col-form-label">Requester Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="requesterName" type="text" id="requesterName" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." placeholder="Ex: Jane Doe" required/>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>


 <div class="form-group row teamname teams">
   <label for="teamName" class="col-form-label">Team Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="teamName" type="text" id="teamName" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid team name." placeholder="Ex: PortalHelp Team" required/>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group row userCount">
   <label for="userCount" class="col-form-label">Total Users:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="userCount" type="number" id="userCount" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid number." placeholder="Ex: 25" required/>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row teams total">
     <label for="totalUsers" class="col-form-label">Number of Attendees:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="totalUsers">
          <option value="Five" selected>5</option>
          <option value="Six">6</option>
          <option value="Seven">7</option>
          <option value="Eight">8</option>
          <option value="Nine">9</option>
          <option value="Ten">10</option>
        </select>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row one teams">
        <label for="oneUser" class="col-form-label">Names of Attendees:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="oneUser" type="text" id="oneUser" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." placeholder="Ex: John Smith" required/>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-group row two teams">
        <input class="form-control" name="twoUsers" type="text" id="twoUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
   </div>

      <div class="form-group row three teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="threeUsers" type="text" id="threeUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row four teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="fourUsers" type="text" id="fourUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row five teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="fiveUsers" type="text" id="fiveUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row six teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="sixUsers" type="text" id="sixUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row seven teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="sevenUsers" type="text" id="sevenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row eight teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="eightUsers" type="text" id="eightUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

   <div class="form-group row nine teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="nineUsers" type="text" id="nineUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row ten teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="tenUsers" type="text" id="tenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <button type="button" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" name="cancelbutton" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" onclick="window.location.href='/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Training.aspx'">Cancel</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Omg is soo complex and chaotic.  Why not use just toggle() ?

Comment: Hi @Cristian, I'm still not too comfortable with jQuery so I don't know how to use .toggle well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in your switch statement.
You've assigned option values like "Six, Seven ..." but switch cases are "six, seven ..."
Remember that switch expressions are case sensitive

Fix:
Changes values in html to all lowercase (like six, seven) or capitalize the first later in each switch cases (Six, Seven)

Comment: It's ok because you have only 10 input fields. If you had like 100, your html will be so complex. Use jquery .append next time https://api.jquery.com/append/